# What to put in switch cases that have nothing to do?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, resulttype

I started using Result as a return type and I mostly like it but when I have nothing to return for success then I am at a loss about what to do in that case statement. Any hints?

All that I could think of was `let _ = 0`

```swift
func createAppDirectory(_ searchPath: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory) -> Result<Void,Error>
...

    switch createAppDirectory(searchPath) {
    case .success(_): let _ = 0
    case .failure(let error): return .failure(error)
    }
```

I am beginning to think that maybe Result isn't a good fit when the success type is Void.

BTW createAppDirectory just creates `Library/Application Support/<Bundle ID>`. There is no value to return if it succeeds.

Comment: It's generally better to make the function throwing rather than returning a `Result` when it's synchronous

Comment: You could also essentially covert it to a throwing function at the call site by calling it as `try createAppDirectory(searchPath).get()`

Comment: @MichealSalmon As a matter of API design, wouldn't it be more useful to have the path be returned? `let path = createAppDirectory(.userDirectory).get()` (or handle the `Result` in some other way, beside `.get()`

Comment: I am using .applicationSupportDirectory but that doesn't really change anything. If anything I would change the function so that it accepted a file url and created the directory containing that file if required. Returning the directory path seems more like a side effect. It's a matter of taste I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a break statement:

```
switch createAppDirectory(searchPath) {
case .success: 
  break
case .failure(let error): return .failure(error)
}
```

### EDIT:

As Mojtaba pointed out, if you're not going to use the associated value for a particular case of your enum you can simply skip it. I've edited my answer above to remove the `(_)` from the `.success` case

Comment: And nothing is wrong with adding a comment like /* do nothing */ to make the intention clear.

Comment: You can also get rid of that underscore.

Answer (score 3):

Just ignore it:

```
case .success: break
```

Also if you want absolutely no overwork when it isn't failure case, `gaurd` it at the very beginning of the scope:

```
guard case .failure(let error) = createAppDirectory(searchPath) else { return <#Value#> }
```

Comment: You say "just ignore it", but the way to ignore it is to use a break statement, just like you did you your answer. The answer is to use `break` rather than a dummy statement like `let _ = 0`.

Comment: I meant *ignore the success case*.

Comment: Right, but the whole point of the OPs question was that he couldn't figure out how to get an empty case to compile without a throw-away `let _ = 0`. The break is how you make the do-nothing `.success` case compile.

Answer (score 1):

If only the error is significant `Result` is inappropriate.

A better pattern is to `throw` the error and return nothing

```
func createAppDirectory(_ searchPath: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory) throws
```

...

```
do {
    try createAppDirectory(searchPath)
} catch { print(error)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return simple void result,

```
switch createAppDirectory(searchPath) {
case .success: return .success(())
case .failure(let error): return .failure(error)
}
```